# choose values from dataframe columns depending on a column holding column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

For example if I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3,4,5], 'c':['a','a','b']})
```

I want to make a result column so that the output will be

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3,4,5], 'c':['a','a','b'], 'res':[0, 1, 5]})
```

where the "res" column value is taken from column 'a' if column 'c' contains value 'a' etc.
Actually I have many columns so I want to avoid hard-coding pd.where(df.c=='a', ...)
Is there some idiomatic way to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### solution 1: using apply

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) per row to get the index an fetch the corresponding value

```
df['res'] = df.apply(lambda s: s[s['c']], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  res
0  0  3  a    0
1  1  4  a    1
2  2  5  b    5
```

### solution 2: direct slicing

Here is a much faster alternative by slicing directly the underlying numpy array:

```
# first map the columns to their position (a->0, b->1…)
cols = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(df.columns)}
# slice the elements
df['res'] = df.values[df.index, df['c'].map(cols)]
```

### solution 3

Finally, a funny alternative with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`numpy.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) to get the diagonal (**warning: this is very memory inefficient**):

```
import numpy as np
df['res'] = np.diag(df.loc[df.index, df['c']])
```